# What will permanently fill the hollow backs of alloy pendants?

Tags: adhesives, metal, jewelry

I have two crescent shaped 3" alloy pendants with hollow backs (like a scooped out avocado). I want to fill the hollows, insert a two-pronged hairpin between them and attach the pendants back to back.

It would be best if one material could both fill and adhere, but if this is impossible, what material can be used to fill, and what separate material will glue the two sides together?

Comment: Please add an image. It can be difficult to imagine what you're talking about while an image will let us see it exactly!

Comment: No way to take a picture at present :-(.   Hollow, like an avocado after you scoop out the insides ...

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could determine the exact type of alloy your pendants are made of, and if they are painted or coated in any way (in which case they may require sanding, chemical etching, or a primer to get the best bond). There are many multi-use products that could work, but you will achieve the best result using an adhesive made specifically for the metals in your pendants and for your application. For example, if your pendants will be exposed to water/humidity, or UV light, look for an adhesive made to withstand those conditions, or apply a protective top coat after the adhesive is dry. If you need to retain a certain degree of flex, or if you need the bond to dry clear, look for adhesives with those properties, and so on.

Comment: I would add that last sentence as a comment on the question. It doesn't really belong in the answer.

Comment: After posting the composition of your alloy, and more details about your application, it might be helpful to add a "chemistry" tag to your question.

Comment: Just a note, chemistry wouldn't be a proper tag. Jewelry should be sufficient, but metalworking could be applicable.

Answer (score -2):

I think resin would be the answer.

Comment: or a high-density foam if weight is an issue.  In either case, the trick will be finding (or creating) something for the filler to grab onto.  Maybe solder a fish hook or a part of a paper clip into the inside of each half, then let the filler surround these new additions before hardening.

Comment: Resin could very well be a solution here. This answer could be better if you justify the choice with more that _I think_. Even better would be some examples of this process being done to compliment the suggestion.

Comment: We generally look for more than one-liners, so it'd be helpful if you could [edit] this to include some details as to _why_ resin would be a good fit, and especially if you could recommend some type(s) of resin, as it's technically a broad category.